# How to express "getting promoted/demoted on the corporate ladder" in Russian

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I just said:

> Если его за это **понизят в ранге**, ему почти нечего будет сказать в свое оправдание.

Here I wanted to express the idea of getting demoted on the **corporate** ladder, or more specifically, in the medical field. I'm wavering between "ранг" and "звание" -- when to use which:

> Если его за это **понизят в звании**, ему почти нечего будет сказать в свое оправдание.

Comment: **в должности** could fit, but really depends on the actual circumstance, could be **категория**, **разряд**, especially if the demotion only affects payment, **звание** is mainly pertinent to military and law enforcement, **ранг** - to navy and justice system

Answer (score 2):

The term **"ранг"** is appropriate mainly for the military and some government officials.
The term **"звание"** is used more broadly, but is also limited in application.
In fact, each sphere has its own analogue of the term **"ранг"**. For medical professionals it's **"[медицинская] категория"**, to workers it's **"[квалификационный] разряд"**, etc.

However, the term **"ранг"** can be used in a figurative sense. In that case it can be attributed to a very wide range of applications. And in some cases, you can simply say **"положениие в [корпоративной] иерархии"**.

Also, do not forget about the term **"должность"**. This is not the same as **"ранг"**, because the relationship between **"ранг"** and **"занимаемая должность"** in many areas is only indirect.
But sometimes **"должность"** may be the most appropriate in the discussion about promotion/demotion on the corporate ladder.

Comment: Put должность first, because it's what is asked about. Понизить в должности.

Comment: @Elena I'm not sure about it. Maybe author was referring to the medical category. It depends a lot on the context of the conversation.